# Vectorization and vector indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization

I currently need to speed up my code a bit and therefore want to use vectorization instead of loops. The following code is a (very) simplified version of the code that gets called a lot during my computation:

```
    T=10; n=5; w0 = 25000; w1 = 23000; b0 = 15000; 
    vec = zeros(1,T+2*n+1); vec(1:n+1) = w0; vec(n+2:n+T+1) = b0; vec(n+T+2:T+2*n+2) = w1;
    ref0=zeros(1,n);
    for i = 1:n
        ref0(i) = sum(vec(T+i+2:n+T+i+2));
    end
```

I tried to use vectorization, but unfortunately it does not seem to work as only the first entry of my vector i is used as an input in the vector indexing process:

```
i = 1:n;
ref1 = sum(vec(T+i+2:n+T+i+2));
```

The output is the following:

```
ref0 =

  106000      114000      122000      130000      138000

ref1 =

  106000
```

Is there any way to achieve that ref1 gives the same output as ref0 using the vectorization? It might be super obvious, but I do not seem to get further here. I am grateful for any help! Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is because the colon operator `:` does not accept vectors as inputs and only uses the first element of the vector input instead

Comment: Vecotrization does not necessarily mean faster. Did you profile your code?

Comment: `vec` is initialised to `T+2*n+1` columns, and then column `2*n+T+2` is assigned a value... not the vectorisation issue, just may want correcting?

Comment: You should take a step back and not think "vectorization", but think "analytical". It seems you are constructing a piece-wise linear sampled function. can you reformulate the parameters you start with into parameters for 2 lines(including the point of intersection)? If so, that beats any number-crunching, vectorized or otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`movsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movsum.html) instead of your loop:

```
ref1 = movsum(vec(T+3:T+2*n+2),n+1,'Endpoints','discard');
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be pretty efficient if `n` and `T` have small values and `vec` is a long vector:

```
ref1 = cumsum(vec);
ref1 = ref1(T+n+3:end) - ref1(T+2:end-n-1);
```

Comment: upvote because it is a different function then movsum, but especially for large vectors "vec", this should be slower then using movsum, because the second line is also not a trivial operation. Someone with Matlab could maybe give some timings for the fun of it.

Answer (score 2):

Convolution also works:

```
c = conv(ones(1,n+1), vec(T+3:2*n+T+2), 'same' );
ref2 = c(1:end-1);
```